# Tibco BW 6 : JDBCQuery timeout after a period of inactivity

Tags: oracle11g, timeout, tibco-business-works

My problem is with Tibco BW 6.

I'm using a JDBCQuery activity to query my database. Everything works well, but when I deploy my application and after a period of inactivity, when I relaunch my test, I have a timeout error at the level of the JDBCQuery activity. I tried to increase the "Login Timeout" of the JDBC resource used and the "Timeout" of the activity but I still have the same problem.

When I restart the application, everything is working well again.

I'm using Oracle as DBMS.

Has someone already had this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: I asumme this is Businessworks 6? We had similar issues with JDBC/SQL Server. However that was fixed with a ticket to TIBCO. The reason was connection turn stale after a while. In "old" Businessworks5 those were checked if stale before usage which was not the case in BW6, might be the same issue you are facing

Comment: Yes it's BW 6. Do you know the version where we fixed the problem?  I'm using 6.3.4.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this workaround by using  a keep me alive process:

```
select * from dual;
```

EDIT:
Probably the BW 6.4 will handle this issue

Comment: Thanks but it's just a palliative/rokhs solution. I'm looking for a solution without using palliative solutions

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I checked the release notes but I didn't find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The TIBCO solution it's to use the property  **Engine.DBConnection.idleTimeout** in AppNodeConfig. But it's not implemently on version 6.4.1

Comment: Thanks @Issam, I switched to 6.4.2 version, I'll check if the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Please check yours jars. We had similar issue wherein, all the jdbc query activities were getting timed out after deployment.

Later we figured out that the Appnode was created when we had wrong ojdbc.jar file installed and was not able to pick the right jar. We just deleted the appnode, recreated it and used 'bwinstall' utility to install the jdbc driver and the issue was fixed. Seems to issue with Appnode.